# In Lotus Notes 8.5.3 when selecting the TO: field it will not show a local address book

Tags: lotus-notes

We have one sales person that can not get access to our address book when he clicks the TO: button in a new email.

He can, however, still type a first name and the name in the address book comes up as an option. This name is coming from the same address book he can't look at from the TO: button.

The address book on the server is missing from 'Select Addresses'.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more precise than "can not get access to our address book"?  What happens?  Does the addressing dialog come up at all?  Does your company address book not show up in the Directory drop-down in the dialog? If it shows up, does anything happen when he selects it?  Does any error message show up when he tries this?

Comment: If you want to comment on existing answers but already lost your account cookie, flag your question for moderator attention to get both accounts merged.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Lotus Notes mail Box
2. File > Preferences
3. Locations > Under Current locations "Select the Location which you uses"
4. Click on Edit > mail > Mail addressing : **Local then Server** or **Server then Local**.
5. OK > OK.
6. Now goto new message > Click on TO > Check the directory option.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into preferences-->mail-->sending and receiving, and explicitly listing it in the "local address books" line.  Generally the local name and address book is called names.nsf

You can also try going into the user's \data\ folder and blanking everything but the first 5-6 lines of the notes.ini, leave a blank line at the end and save it.  This will prompt you to reconfigure notes for the user the next time you launch it.

If you have any agents you run after initially setting up Notes for a user, you may have to re-run those as well.